# What's wrong with this regex that matches a string and not the negated version of it

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace the phrases containing a word but not the negated version of it, for example, map all containing `gain` to `gain` and all containing `no gain` to `no gain`

This is the R code I used:

```
gsub("^((?!No).)*Gain.*","No Gain","No Gain in this transaction",
ignore.case=TRUE)
```

And the error returned:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "gsub("^((?!No).)*Gain.*","No Gain",""No"

Edit: I need to replace multiple patterns in a data frame column. It works on a list but somehow doesn't work on a date frame:

```
 m <- c(".*No gain.*",".*loss.*","[^(No )].*gain.*") 
 n <- c("No
 gain","loss","gain") 
 dd <- c("No gain ","previous loss","declined")
 for(i in seq_along(m)) dd <- gsub(m[i], n[i], dd,ignore.case=TRUE) 
 dd

 df=data.frame(outcome=c("gain 123","increased 1k","declined","previous
 loss","no gain")) 
 for(i in seq_along(m)) df$outcome1 <- gsub(m[i], n[i], df$outcome,ignore.case=TRUE,perl = T) 
 df
```

Comment: You are using a TRE regex. Add `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: `"[^(No )].*gain.*"` is a wrong pattern. `[^(No )]` matches 1 single char that is not `(`, `N`, `o`, space and `)`.

Comment: what would be the right way to do it?

Comment: The question is - to do what? Match `gain` that has no `"No "` before? If there is only one space - `"(?<!\\bNo )\\bgain\\b"` with `perl=TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

The error you mention happens because you have too many quotes in `""No Gain in this transaction"` which begins with two quotes. If the text really begins with a quote you need to escape it with a backslash: `"\"No Gain in this transaction"`.

However this does not solve your problem because the you'l get an error `invalid regular expression`. This second error happens because this sort of "extended" regex is only possible with parameter `perl = T`

Edit: In my opinion it would be better to use `grepl` in combination with `ifelse` to achieve what you want, because it is much clearer and quite possibily also faster.

Edit2: An example: (Note that I have altered your regex a bit)

```
test <- c(
    "No Gain here",
    "Gain 1234",
    "Gain hjk",
    "No Gain abcd",
    "No Gain gain!")

ifelse(grepl("^((?!No).?)Gain.*", test, perl = T, ignore.case = T),
       "Gain",
       "No Gain")
```

Comment: thanks. that was very helpful. how can i use grep in this case and why is grep faster than gsub? and if i need to apply the text replacement of several patterns on a column in data frame, is there anything I need to use (lapply?) ?

Comment: I added an example how to use `grepl` (I forgot the "l" and wrote `grep` in error) with `ifelse`. 
I think this is faster because you always create a fixed string as replacement, while the result of `gsub` could in theory always be different.
I don't think that you'll need `lapply` because all functions here are vectorized, but I also do not know what you want to do exactly ;)

Comment: i added an example on using string replacement on a data frame, somehow it doesn't work as expected

Comment: It has nothing to do with the data.frame; the logic is flawed. In the first version (without data.frame) you alter the vector `dd` in each iteration and apply the next substitution to the already altered vector.
In the second version (with data.frame) you always overwrite `outcome1` with the replacement on the *original* `outcome`. Which means that effectively only the last substitution is executed.
Again, I would strongly recommend that you use `grepl` and `ifelse` for clarity. The way you plan to do it implicitly highly depends on the order of replacements and is prone to errors.